# Settings charm dialogue is hidden below the main application?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Hi I'm developing a Win8 app using javascript and HTML5 and was currently working on adding various tabs for the settings charm. Now when I originally added the pages for each tab, when you tap on the tab it didn't show anything. When I put the app into snapped mode I noticed that the page for that particular tab was showing up at the bottom of the screen. I've copied line by line the [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780611.aspx) from MSDN.

I did notice that when it appears at the bottom of the screen it looks like a page with no style. I'm thinking somehow the styles aren't getting applied. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of had a feeling it was a styling issue. I was using a third party application that generates a VS2012 JavaScript project automatically. The only problem is that it didn't include the references to system style sheets. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-light.css" />
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Great to hear!  Don't forget you also get access to UI Dark.

```
  <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The // location in the href tells the Windows Store app that this file will automatically be added to your app package as part of the WinJS libraries.

Having to troubleshoot CSS styles is a very common thing you will run into.  Fortunately. there is a DOM Explorer tool built into Visual Studio 2012 now that will allow you to trace Styles and see if individual elements have inherited the correct styles or not.

This has saved me a couple times already.  =)  If you have ever used the IE Dev tools they are extremely similar.  Here is a link on MSDN that shows tracing CSS Styles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh696632.aspx